# Wifi internet issues on iPad

Tags: wifi, ipad, settings, internet

I have a wifi internet router (via an ADSL modem) which i use to connect internet on my iPad. For some reasons, the connection seems to break in between (and more when idle).
The same connection works fine on my desktop.

Is there any setting i need to make on the iPad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is something wrong with the wireless portion of the router. Do other wireless internet devices have the same problem? (By desktop I am assuming that it is a wired Ethernet connection)

Regardless, there is nothing that you can do on your iPad to fix the problem.

Comment: The same wifi works fine on thedesktop..

Comment: By that you mean that the desktop is wireless, not wired?

Comment: If so, you should contact an apple service rep and ask apple to examine your ipad's wireless card. Don't let them charge you anything, because this isn't your fault.